# getting "NaN" as result in Rcmdr for the order: qnorm(c(1.96), mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=TRUE)

Tags: r

I just started using R / Rcmdr. My problem is that when I make simple order in Rcmdr like "qnorm(c(1.96), mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=TRUE)" I get "NaN" as result. Does somebody have any idea what the problem might be and how it could be solved? maybe incorrect installing of R? The point is that simple calculations like 5+5, oder 5*5 brings me correct results, but the above order doesn't.

Thanks for any help
and best regards,
Serdarius

Comment: youre either confusing pnorm and qnorm or are using the wrong probability

Comment: And the `c(.)` is useless, it's a vector of just one element. With two or more yes, you must use function `c()`. @rawr `qnorm(0.975)  [1] 1.959964`. (No `lower.tail`.)

Comment: Thanks to you both "rawr" and "Rui Barradas"! Your inputs did help me! Wish you both a nice week.

Answer (score 2):

In R, providing incorrect inputs to a function may produce NaN without any explanation. In the case of the qnorm function, the input p should be a probability value between 0 and 1 (inclusive). If you provide a p value greater than 1 or less than 0, the qnorm function will return NaN.

For example, with mean = 0 and sd = 1:

```
qnorm(1.96, mean = 0, sd = 1) # This will produce NaN, as the p value is greater than 1
```

Providing a p value of 1 produces “Inf” and 0 produces "-Inf":

```
qnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1) # This will produce Inf
```

A p value between 0-1 will produce a value you can use:

```
qnorm(0.05, mean = 0, sd = 1) # This will produce -1.644854
```